# Datagrid selected index in the delete command

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

i am using asp.net, c#. I want the selected index for the current row which is selected by the user.

Thans in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Given the question does not have any specifics, you can simply use the datagrid's `SelectedIndex` property.  Am I missing something here?